# How to add datepicker using jquery in version 1.12.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a date picker with jquery 1.12.4.

What I tried:

```
jQuery('input[name="dates"]').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
```

but I didn't get any results in the page.
There is anyone who knows what is the mistake in my code?

I m getting this in the console:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

Comment: jQuery 1.x has been end of life for years. It does not get security updates. It has known vulnerabilities. You should not use it. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: Where are you trying to add ? And why not use the latest jQuery version.

Comment: ["it's not working"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a helpful description of the problem. Nor is a code example that isn't a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that i added jquery-ui to the head. and the style.css.
also i change the function you wrote to this one:

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
```

now it should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

to read more: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat
for code pen: https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/mdPdBEg